# Issue with win calculation when the computer wins in my 'TicTacToe' app

Tags: ios, swift, tic-tac-toe

I am currently developing a Swift-based app to play Tic-Tac-Toe, and I've encountered an issue with correctly calculating wins when playing against the computer.

In my app, I've implemented logic to keep track of the number of wins for both the player and the computer. Wins are calculated correctly when two users play against each other, but when I play against the computer, the computer's wins aren't calculated correctly. Instead of increasing from 0 to 1 when the computer wins, it remains at 0 all the time.

I have reviewed my code carefully and couldn't find any obvious errors. I suspect that the issue might lie in my checkForWinner() function or how I handle win calculation when playing against the computer.

I would appreciate it if someone could review my code and offer insights into what might be causing this behavior or if there are any best practices for handling win calculations when playing against a computer.

Here is my code:

```swift
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // All my outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var turnSign: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
    
    var currentPlayer: Int = 1 // To keep track of player
    var playerOneName: String? // To store player one name in variable
    var playerTwoName: String? // To store player two name in variable
    var winner: String?
    var boardArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""] // An array of empty strings
    var countPlayer1 = 0
    var countPlayer2 = 0
    let playAgainstComputer = GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer 
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        boardArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
        
        // If it's player 1's turn -> update our labelSign text
        if (currentPlayer == 1) {
            turnSign.text = playerOneName
        } else {
            turnSign.text = playerTwoName
        }
        print("Initial currentPlayer: \(currentPlayer)")
    }
    
    // A function to switch turn between player 1 and 2
    func switchPlayers() {
        if currentPlayer == 1 {
            currentPlayer = 2
        } else {
            currentPlayer = 1
        }
    }
    
    /**
     In this function I want to set a  title on a button and then switch turn when a button is pressed
     All the buttons are attached to this function so that "let index" will include same terms for all my buttons
     **/
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let index = sender.tag
        if boardArray[index] == "" {
            if currentPlayer == 1 {
                print("Before currentPlayer update: \(currentPlayer)")
                boardArray[index] = "X"
                sender.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
            } else {
                boardArray[index] = "O"
                sender.setTitle("O", for: .normal)
            }
            
            sender.setTitle(boardArray[index], for: .normal)
            
            switchPlayers()
            
            if currentPlayer == 1 {
                print("Before currentPlayer update: \(currentPlayer)")
                turnSign.text = playerOneName
            } else {
                turnSign.text = playerTwoName
            }
            
            if let winnerMessage = checkForWinner() {
                    self.winner = winnerMessage
                    myAlertMessage(winnerMessage: winnerMessage)
                }
            } else if !boardArray.contains("") {
                myAlertMessage(winnerMessage: "It's a tie!")
            }
            if GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer && currentPlayer == 2 {
                print("Before currentPlayer update: \(currentPlayer)")
                playAgainstNPC()
            }
        }
    
    
    // A function to check for a winner
    func checkForWinner() -> String? {
        let winningPatterns: [[Int]] = [
            [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
            [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
        ]
        
        if GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer && currentPlayer == 2 {
            if !boardArray.contains("") {
                return "It's a tie!"
            }
            return nil
        }
        for pattern in winningPatterns {
            let positions = pattern.map { boardArray[$0] }
            if positions == ["X", "X", "X"] {
                if GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer {
                    if currentPlayer == 1 {
                        print("Before currentPlayer update: \(currentPlayer)")
                        countPlayer1 += 1
                    }
                    return "Congrats \(playerOneName ?? "X"), you won!"
                } else {
                    print("Before currentPlayer update: \(currentPlayer)")
                    countPlayer1 += 1
                    return "Congrats \(playerOneName ?? "X"), you won!"
                }
            } else if positions == ["O", "O", "O"] {
                if GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer {
                    if currentPlayer == 2 {
                        print("Before currentPlayer update: \(currentPlayer)")
                        countPlayer2 += 1
                    }
                    return "Congrats \(playerTwoName ?? "O"), you won!"
                } else {
                    countPlayer2 += 1
                    return "Congrats \(playerTwoName ?? "O"), you won!"
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        if boardArray.contains("") {
            return nil
        } else {
            return "Oh, it's a beutiful tie!"
        }
    }
    
    // This i my alert message after every win/tie
    func myAlertMessage(winnerMessage: String) {
       
        
        let crossesText = "Crosses: \(countPlayer1)"
        let noughtsText = "Noughts: \(countPlayer2)"
        
        let messageText = "Do you wanna play again?\n\n\(crossesText)\n\(noughtsText)"
        
        let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: winnerMessage, message: messageText, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) {_ in
            self.resetGame()
        }
        let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel) {_ in
            self.dismissGame()
        }
        
        myAlertController.addAction(yesAction)
        myAlertController.addAction(noAction)
        
        present(myAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // This function resets the game and prepare for a new game
    func resetGame() {
        boardArray = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
        for button in buttons {
            button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            button.isEnabled = true
        }
        currentPlayer = 1
        turnSign.text = playerOneName
    }
    
    
    // This function allows me to close the game in GameViewController and go back to SecondViwController
    func dismissGame() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    
    /*
     This function allows computer to make a move
     It searches for empty spots in the game and make it's move randomly
     */
    func makeComputerMove() {
        var emptySpots = [Int]()
        for (index, value) in boardArray.enumerated() {
            if value.isEmpty {
                emptySpots.append(index)
            }
        }
        
        if let randomIndex = emptySpots.randomElement(){
            let buttonToPress = buttons[randomIndex]
            buttonTapped(buttonToPress)
        }
    }
    
    /*
     This function controlls if the game is between a user and computer
     If it's true, it allows the computer to make a move
     */
    func playAgainstNPC() {
        if GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer == true && currentPlayer == 2 {
            makeComputerMove()
        }
    }

}

    
import Foundation

class GameSettings {
    static let shared = GameSettings()
    var playAgainstComputer = false
}

    import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    let TO_GAME_SCREEN = "toGameScreen"
    var playAgainstComputer = GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer
  
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPlayerOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPlayerTwo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnNavigate: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPlayNPC: UIButton!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func btnNavigate(_ sender: UIButton) {
        GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer = false
        performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_GAME_SCREEN, sender: self)
    }
    
    
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == TO_GAME_SCREEN {
            
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? GameViewController {
                
                guard let txtPlayerOne = txtPlayerOne.text else {return}
                guard let txtPlayerTwo = txtPlayerTwo.text else {return}
                
                destinationVC.playerOneName = txtPlayerOne.isEmpty ? "X" : txtPlayerOne
                destinationVC.playerTwoName = txtPlayerTwo.isEmpty ? "O" : txtPlayerTwo
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func btnPlayNPC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer = true
        txtPlayerOne.text = "Player"
        txtPlayerTwo.text = "Computer"
        performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_GAME_SCREEN, sender: self)
    }
    
}
```

When I play against computer it prints out:

> Initial currentPlayer: 1 in my output.

After I make my first move in the game, I get these outputs:

> Before currentPlayer update: 1
> Before currentPlayer update: 2
> Before currentPlayer update: 1

Comment: You haven’t included all the code so it’s hard to tell but I see you have an extra if condition when using a computer player, `if currentPlayer == 1` so I would focus my troubleshooting on the variable `currentPlayer` and try to follow how it is set.

Comment: What is the value of `currentPlayer` when you are playing against the computer?

Comment: Do you mean that I have an extra if condition in this part of the code: ``` if positions == ["X", "X", "X"] {
                if GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer {
                    if currentPlayer == 1 {
                        countPlayer1 += 1
                    } ``` @JoakimDanielson

Comment: When playing against the computer, I have set the currentPlayer value to 2 for the computer's turn. This can be seen in my playAgainstNPC() function: ```func playAgainstNPC() {
    if GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer == true && currentPlayer == 2 {
        makeComputerMove()
    }
} ```So, when playing against the computer, currentPlayer is set to 2, indicating it's the computer's turn. When it's the player's turn, currentPlayer is set to 1. @JeremyP

Comment: Not an extra (as in incorrect) but what I mean is that is something that is specific for when you use a computer player so it's a possible cause of the error since the code works fine when there are two human players. So look into how you use `currentPlayer` since it might not be what you expect to be when one player is a computer.

Comment: You are comparing agains two, `== 2`, there is nowhere in your posted code you actually set the `currentPlayer` to anything. Why not add some print statements to your code to see what value it contains?

Comment: I added some print statements to my code. Can you please check my code, I updated it so you now can see all my code. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Your code is still not complete, the defintion of `GameSettings` is missing.

Comment: I didn't think It was necessary but now you can see the definition of GameSettings and SecondViewController @soundflix